# Unable to execute WorkManager from Xposed Injected code

Tags: android, android-workmanager, xposed

I have a couple of classes that are loaded and executed inside third party apps using **Xposed** hooks.

One of the methods takes a lot of resources and crashes the App where it runs. I figured out I would run it using the **WorkManager** so the load will be automatically handled by the system.

The classes injected are not part of a normal Android App (Manifest doesn't have the application tag, and even if it did It wouldn't run as a normal App). Rather the classes are compiled and loaded inside the third party app then executed directly inside.

Since **WorkManager** relies on the **Application** to create an instance, I figured out that maybe I could just create the instance manually.

So somewhere in the code I called:

```
WorkManager.initialize(context, new Configuration.Builder().build());
```

Then in my method I used something like :

```
WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
mWorkManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(MyWorker.class));
```

However during the initialization I get the following error:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020002 type #0x3 is not valid
```

I'm not sure what resources the **WorkManager** is looking for, as I mentioned before I just have couple classes, no **res** folder

I'm open to other suggestions to replace the **WorkManager**

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager does look for resources to determine if it needs to enable / disable `Scheduler`'s based on API level. Here is the actual file in question (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/res/values/values.xml).

I don't know why these resources are not getting merged correctly.

Comment: Can it be related to Proguard ? or maybe because the code gets injected through Xposed so resources are not part of it ?